# "I teach" vs. "I'm teaching" — which one is proper in this situation?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, present-tense, progressive-aspect

Following situation occurs/ed. I meet a friend for a coffee. We chat and I ask him what he's doing for work now.

His answer: "I'm teaching English."

This irks me. Because in that situation he's not teaching right that moment, but rather he teaches English. So shouldn't his answer rather be "I teach English."?

English is not my mother tongue but I do think I'm fluent in it. I grew up bilingual.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Except for the fact that I'm not a new user learning English as my second language. Even the native speakers have troubles and they come here to ask.

Comment: If you think the progressive is ungrammatical in this context, why did you ask him what he **is doing**?

Comment: Yes, the sites are perhaps misnamed. 'More basic' and 'more advanced' would perhaps fit better.

Comment: @StoneyB Spot on. Jealous.

Comment: In the archives of EL&U I have seen many many questions that were EXTREMELY basic, that received numerous upvotes and excellent answers. This is a simple question but lets not fool ourselves, native speakers aren't infallible, and the majority haven't a clue about grammar because they weren't taught it. At least this question was clear, well written and the OP explained his dilemma. A darn sight more than the majority of questions we have been receiving of late (end of rant).

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I'd have thought all truly native speakers would correctly interpret even the fine distinction made in your answer (present continuous often implies *for the time being*). The business about asking *"What do you do?"* or *"What are you doing?"* (or including the word *now*) seems even more "intuitive". These are things native speakers *know*, even if they were never taught anything about the "grammar" (terminology, justification, etc.) involved.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I agree with you, but when faced with the problem of explaining *why* something is *right* or *wrong* many native speakers are unable to verbalise their reasons, limiting themselves to saying... "because that's how it is" or "because it sounds right" If I had to answer this question thirty years ago, I wouldn't have had a clue.

Comment: @StoneyB Well, now that you said it...I guess that's worth taking into consideration.

Comment: @DonSalva Keep in mind that in conversation people tend to echo the forms used by their interlocutors. If you had said "What do you do these days?" he would have been more likely to answer, "Oh, I teach English." But that's a tendency, no more.

Comment: @DonSalva - what a stickler for detail! *What are you doing these days?* Does that limit the response to daytime activities? What if he works nights? Must he answer *nothing but sleeping?* Language isn't a blunt instrument with which to batter one's acquaintances.

Comment: @medica Yes, I know. I get it now. Sometimes my gut-feeling of what's right is wrong though overpowering. After all I'm not a native speaker, even though I grew up bilingual. A gut feeling is a gut feeling, everybody has them every once in a while. This was mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: What are you doing at the moment?

A: I'm teaching English at a language school.

Does this mean the person is teaching at the moment of speaking. No, it doesn't. We use the [present continuous tense](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/present-continuous-tense.html) to talk about things that are in progress or for actions  that are, for the time being, temporary in nature. The fact your friend replied using the present continuous means he does not consider teaching to be his permanent job, it is a stopover, something he is doing now, for a limited period. Of course, he could always change his mind and become a full-time fully fledged teacher, but his answer was grammatical and perfectly acceptable.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous_%28English%29)

> The present continuous is used in several instances.
>
> - To describe something which is happening at the exact moment of
>   speech:
>   *The boy is crying.*
> - To describe an action that is taking place now, but
>   not at the exact moment of speech:
>   *He is working in Dubai*.
> - To describe an event which is planned in the
>   future:
>   *I'm resitting my French exam on Tuesday.*
> - With always, but meaning often:
>   *My mother is always making me go to school!*
>   *She is always playing with that doll!*

Comment: @Mari-LouAI was tempted to downvote it myself because of this, " The fact your friend replied using the present continuous means he does not consider teaching to be his permanent job, it is a stopover, something he is doing now, for a limited period." I said almost the exact same sentence a few weeks ago because someone in the same district as me knew that I had left the school he was in.  I simply changed schools; I have no intention of leaving that school or the profession:  "I am teaching at X." That being said, you answered the question and did not deserve a downvote.

Comment: Downvoter reversed vote (must've read the answer).

Comment: That or I convinced him with gentle reasoning!

Comment: Thanks for all the effort Mari-Lou. Much obliged. Even though I did know about present continuous, I'm neither a native speaker nor infallible and do forget. I'm after all human, and make mistakes too.

Comment: Mmm ... It *may* imply that he thinks of his teaching as temporary, but that's at most an implicature, not an entailment - and me, I don't think it's even that absent some contextual support. I think it's just the ordinary response to the question asked: "Whatcha doing?" - "Teaching English."

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the circumstance.

If you are actually in a classroom, teaching an English class and a student asks:

"What are you doing right now?"

A correct response would be:

"I am teaching English."

The response describes your current activity.

If, however, the student asks:

"What is your occupation?"

The correct response would be:

"I teach English."

This response describes your occupation.

Two different questions, two different answers.

Comment: Mmm ... "I teach English" is **a** correct response, but so is "I am teaching English". Strictly speaking, the response most literally suited to the question "What is your occupation?" would be "[It is] English teacher."

Comment: @StoneyB I agree that there are many "correct" correct responses to either question.

Answer (score 2):

It is the difference between present progressive and simple present.

---

"So what are you doing nowadays, Don?"

"I am teaching English."

You taught English yesterday, now, and tomorrow.

**As to your annoyance**:

Your understanding of the progressive tense is that you have to be doing the thing right that very second, but that would mean we would never say "am running" unless we are on the phone panting because we are running while talking.

As you can see, the posed question asked what his profession is and was, what he has been *doing*, so, at this very moment, and in the past, and in the future, he was, is, and will be a teacher of English.

---

"What do you do, Don?"

"I teach English."

Simple present--right now, I teach English.

---

As for "to teach", "to teach" is an infinitive that can act like a noun, adjective, or adverb.

"I plan to teach English." (Direct Object)

"To teach English is my goal." (Subject)

---

Comment: Well okay, that and the other answers cleared it up. I was aware of the different tenses and whatnot, it just didn't sit right with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend answered "I am teachING English"simply because you asked "What are you doING." If you had asked "What DO you do now?" Your friend's answer would be "I TEACH English."
Please remember your friend IS teaching English (at that time). That's how he teaches his students to answer questions.